# Showing ${\frak c}:=|\Bbb{R}|=2^{\aleph_0}$ using only the axioms of the reals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

It is a well-known fact that the cardinality of the continuum, ${\frak c}:=|\Bbb{R}|$, is the same as the cardinality of the powerset of the natural numbers, but I've tasked myself with proving the result from scratch, and naturally a whole bevy of little issues come up that I hadn't thought of to begin with. The kicker here is that I want to prove this using *only* the axioms of the real numbers, not any construction-dependent facts.

It is sufficient by Schroeder-Bernstein to prove ${\frak c}\le2^{\aleph_0}$ and ${\frak c}\ge2^{\aleph_0}$, and one direction is clear: the function $f(A)=\sum_{i\in A}3^{-i}$ for $A\subseteq\Bbb{N}$ is an injective map from ${\cal P}(\Bbb{N})\approx2^{\aleph_0}$ to the Cantor set, which is a subset of the reals (note that by using $3^{-i}$ instead of $2^{-i}$, I avoid that silly technicality about non-unique decimal expansions), so ${\frak c}\ge2^{\aleph_0}$.

To prove the converse, I don't know whether it can be done using only the axioms (stated [here](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmcomplex.html#axioms)). Given a construction of the reals by Dedekind cuts, we note that each real number is a set of rationals, so $\Bbb{R}\subseteq{\cal P}(\Bbb{Q})\Rightarrow{\frak c}\le2^\Bbb{Q}=2^{\aleph_0}$. Alternatively, if we use Cauchy sequences, we know that each real number is a an equivalence class of sequences of rational numbers, so ${\frak c}\le_*\Bbb{Q^N}=2^{\aleph_0}$ (where the $\le_*$ indicates the existence of a surjection), and after an application of AC, we get ${\frak c}\le2^{\aleph_0}$.

But if I had no construction, can it even be done? I've heard some stuff about $\Bbb{R}$ being "the unique order-complete field up to isomorphism" or something like that, so it should be possible to use a pure axiomatic approach to get the result, but the principal counterexample in my mind is the surreal numbers $\sf{No}$, which (I believe) also satisfy all the listed axioms (except the existence one, since $\sf{No}\supseteq\sf{On}$), and obviously there are a lot more surreal numbers than real numbers. Are there missing axioms that I need to prove this?

Comment: What are "the axioms of the real numbers"? Is it an ordered field? A topological space with certain properties? Is it anything particular?

Comment: Being a field of characteristic zero, $\mathbb R$ contains  a copy of $\mathbb Q$, so after assuming/proving $\mathbb Q$ is dense we can still use cuts.

Comment: Also, in order to say that you can prove something about cardinality from particular axioms, you need to have axioms that can express something similar to cardinality. The real numbers (as a real-closed field) cannot express something like that in first-order logic. So are we talking about second-order logic? Are you allowing something else? Extra predicates? (e.g. $\Bbb Q$ is most certainly not first-order definable in $\Bbb R$ as an ordered-field of any sort - so appealing to the rationals in first-order requires you to have a predicate for them.)

Comment: To finish my previous comment, adding predicates or using second-order logic is already half-cheating because it essentially appeals to the general set theoretical approach, and it allows us to exploit particular constructions of the real numbers (e.g. Dedekind cuts).

Comment: @Asaf I linked the list of axioms. It is an ordered field with the supremum property.

Comment: @Asaf Also, I am working in ZF/ZFC with predicate calculus, so I certainly have the means to state and prove these claims, once they have been made precise. (I didn't mention this because it is usually implicit, i.e. we say we prove things in ZFC even though ZFC itself has no inference rules, so we can't prove anything other than axioms without a logical foundation.)

Comment: The supremum axiom is a second-order axiom. Does that mean that we can quantify over subsets of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm working in a first-order theory (ZF), but the objects are *sets*, not real numbers, so you can quantify over subsets of $\Bbb{R}$, subsets of those, and so on, just not subsets of $V$ (a.k.a. classes). The axioms merely state the existence of a set called $\Bbb{R}$ with some operations, without explicitly giving the structure (as in taking $\Bbb{R}=\{x|\cdots\}$ as an axiom), which is what I would call a "construction of the reals".

Comment: Okay then. Now it's clear.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Also, if you look at the statement of `axsup` in that link, you'll notice that it is a first-order (over the reals) axiom *schema*, not a second order axiom.

Comment: Oh. If this is an axiom schema in the sense that it requires $A$ to be definable, then you cannot prove this because there is a countable field which is real-closed, in which every definable bounded set has a supremum.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Although that is not an issue for my application since I can take $A=\{y|y\in x\}$ for set variable $x$ and generalize it if I need the quantified version, I'm curious about how my proof above breaks down in that circumstance (recall that I am worried about proving that $\Bbb{R}$ is not too *big*; proving that it is uncountable is the easy part and should follow from the axioms without difficulty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I first thought of this problem, it seemed that there would not be a solution, since the supremum axiom only seems to prescribe the existence of new elements, without restricting the set from having extra elements ("nonstandard" reals). But it turns out that it does, and in fact the [surreal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) ($\sf No$) are a prime example of this — the surreals *do not* satisfy the supremum axiom, even though $\Bbb{R}\subseteq\sf No$. Recalling the supremum axiom (taken from the [link](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmcomplex.html#axioms) in the original post):

$$A\subseteq\Bbb{R}\wedge A\ne\emptyset\wedge\exists x\in\Bbb{R}\,\operatorname{ub}_A(x)\to\exists x\in\Bbb{R}\,\left(\operatorname{ub}_A(x)\wedge\forall y<x \ \neg\operatorname{ub}_A(y)\right),$$

where $\operatorname{ub}_A(x)$ abbreviates $\forall z\in A\,x\ge z$. In english, this says that if a nonempty set $A$ of reals has an upper bound, then the set of all upper bounds has a minimum (a least upper bound), also in $\Bbb{R}$.

The place where the surreals go wrong in the set $A=\{2^{-n}\mid n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ (looking at the infimum now for convenience) is that although $0$ is a surreal number, it is no longer the greatest lower bound of $A$ because a whole bunch of new numbers were stuffed between the positive reals and $0$, and now the situation looks more like
$$0<\epsilon<2\epsilon<\cdots<\frac18<\frac14<\frac12<1$$
and so there is no greatest lower bound at all. (In fact, the surreals don't have least upper bounds for any sets at all except ones with a maximum element.)

---

Returning to the proof: We will show that to each $x\in\Bbb{R}$ we can find a distinct sequence of rational numbers that converges to it, thus showing that $|\Bbb{R}|\le|\Bbb{Q^N}|=2^{\aleph_0}$. We will need the following lemma:

Lemma **A** (the Archimedean property): For any $x\in\Bbb{R}$, there is an $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $n>x$. Proof: (Note that this is another property that the surreal numbers don't have.) If there was an $x\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $\forall n\in\Bbb{N},x\ge n$, then $x$ would be an upper bound on $\Bbb{N}$, so there must exist a least upper bound $y$. Then $y-1$ would not be an upper bound, so there is an $n\in\Bbb{N}$ with $n>y-1\to n+1>y$, a contradiction.

Define a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}^*}$ such that $x_n=\lceil nx-1\rceil/n$ is the greatest rational number with denominator $n$ that is strictly less than $x$. This is well-defined by lemma **A**. Then $a_1+1$ is an upper bound for $\{x_n|n\in\Bbb{N}^*\}$, so there is a least upper bound $y$. If $y<x$, then there is some $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\frac1n<x-y$ by lemma **A**, so $x_n+\frac1n\le y+\frac1n<x$, a contradiction. If $y>x$, then since $y$ is l.u.b., $x$ is not an upper bound, so there is some $x_n>x$, a contradiction. Thus $y=x$ and so the least upper bound of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}^*}$ is $x$. This is important because if $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}^*}=(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}^*}$, then they must have the same least upper bound, so $x=y$ and thus the function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{Q^{N^*}}$ defined by $f(x)=(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}^*}$ is injective and ${\frak c}\le2^{\aleph_0}$. (The other inequality is argued in the original question.)

**Edit:** I don't like accepting my own answer, but this is the method I used in my formal proof, and it worked out pretty well. You can browse the result [on Metamath](http://us2.metamath.org:8888/mpegif/rpnnen.html). (The proof of ${\frak c}\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$ turned out to be the harder one, mainly because of all the algebra and convergence results needed to prove the map was well-defined and injective.)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know whether this meets your requirements, but:

The [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is surjective, continuous, and non-decreasing. This function $f$ has the property that the restriction $f\upharpoonright C$ of $f$ to the Cantor set $C$ is also surjective. I have included a graph showing what the function looks like, which should also make its definition clear. (Image found [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/class/harvard/114/07/html/cantor.html).)

[image]

For a good survey of the Cantor function and its properties, see

> O. Dovgoshey, O. Martio, V. Ryazanov, and M. Vuorinen. *The Cantor function*, Expo. Math. **24 (1)**, (2006), 1–37. [MR2195181 (2006k:26005)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2195181).

We can define an injection $g:(0,1)\to C$ by letting $g(x)$ be the first $t\in C$ with $f(t)=x$ (using that $C$ is closed). Since $|C|=2^{\aleph_0}$, we have a proof that $\mathfrak c\le 2^{\aleph_0}$, at least if we accept that $\mathbb R$ and $(0,1)$ have the same size. If we need to argue about this, there are even continuous bijections (such as some appropriate translation/dilation of arc-tangent).

Comment: After unpacking all the definitions there, it would seem that your function $g$ (or more accurately $h\circ g$ where $h$ is the canonical map from $C$ to binary sequences $2^{\aleph_0}$) is exactly a decimal (binary) expansion, where you choose the representation with an infinite number of 1's using your trick with the minimal $t$. I'll admit that proving all that formally is a seemingly formidable task, but more to the point, I don't quite see how you've ruled out the existence of "nonstandard" reals, as in my surreal numbers example.

Comment: How do we know that the Cantor function is continuous? After some deliberation, I'm pretty sure that the proof of the intermediate value theorem still works if there are nonstandard reals, but continuity proofs must then work with possibly infinitesimal $\epsilon$ in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument, and it is obvious that it has to break down at some point, or else we could end up proving that the surreal numbers are bijective with $2^{\aleph_0}$, which is nonsense.

Comment: I think I can make my question even more basic: How do we know that the infimum of the sequence $2^{-n}$, $n\in\Bbb{N}$ is $0$? This is not true for surreals, since $\epsilon=\omega^{-1}$ is also a lower bound for the sequence.