# Comparing the two cardinals $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: set-theory

Is $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ or $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}>2^{\aleph_0}$ Why?

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110211/is-aleph-0-aleph-0-smaller-than-or-equal-to-2-aleph-0)

Comment: Is $\aleph_0 + 1 \gt \aleph_0$ ? Nonsense, right? Why then is $2^{\aleph_0} \gt \aleph_0$ ? I could mock this subject matter. HA. I don't grasp infinite cardinalities of "different sizes". I'm inclined to argue these notions are themselves fallacies of reason.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: I don't think anyone here will argue that cardinal arithmetic is a bit wonky, and often counterintuitive, but it's hardly fallacious. If you don't understand why $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$, I recommend you read [this wonderful and intuitive answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/164185/28900) describing why a power set is always strictly larger than the starting set. P.S.: Your username cracks me up.

Comment: @Cogito: I'm sure many set theorists could mock you for not understanding, but they... ahem... have more [*class*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) than that (this is a joke).

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Such skepticism does seem appropriate from someone whose username suggests that he/she doubts his/her very existence...

Comment: @Zev: I hold mocking someone only after they post several anti-Cantorian and matheological questions and papers to arXiv (or viXra). :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\le\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}\le\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$.